# PHP PDO: How to make num_rows, fetch_array, etc

Tags: php, pdo

I would like to know how to use the common mysql_* stuff. I don't take to make SO a mess and make a question for each one, so I just put up this question with a small list:

- num_rows
- fetch_array
- set_charset
- fetch_row

This is the functions you use to normal mysql_* queries, what are the PDO´s functions equals to these?

And how can you `INSERT INTO, UPDATE and DELETE`

The only thing I know and tested right now is connect to the db + selecting like this:

```
$conn = new PDO("mysql:host=$host;dbname=$db",$user,$pass);
$sql  = "SELECT id FROM users";
$q    = $conn->query($sql) or die("failed!");
```

What I expect for an answer is either links to each function and attributes
`(num_rows, fetch_array, insert into, update, etc..)` or direct answers to them.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> `$q    = $conn->query($sql) or die("failed!");`

Don't do that. Use:

```
$conn = new PDO("mysql:host=$host;dbname=$db", $user, $pass, array(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE => PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION));
```

Then you'll get an exception if something goes wrong with the query.

Answer (score 1):

have a look at the documentation: http://php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php
Its all in there

Comment: Yes but I am getting confused such as this. Should i use e.g $r = $sql->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC) or $r = $sql->fetch() they both work same way?

Comment: Also mentioned there: `fetch()` use `FETCH_BOTH` by default.